# Send Image over BLE iOS

Tags: ios, image, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am sending an image of size approximately 7KB over BLE between two iOS Devices. I am using Core bluetooth framework for the same. In the BTLE Transfer sample given at apple developer there is a sendData method which divides the data into smaller chunks of 20 bytes and send it over bluetooth.But this does not maintain any order. How should I handle the order of each smaller chunk send. Also if a chunk is dropped of, how can I handle that. I can not afford missing any chunk.

```
- (void)sendData
{
    // First up, check if we're meant to be sending an EOM
    static BOOL sendingEOM = NO;

    if (sendingEOM) {

        // send it
        BOOL didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:[@"EOM" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

        // Did it send?
        if (didSend) {

            // It did, so mark it as sent
            sendingEOM = NO;

            NSLog(@"Sent: EOM");
        }

        // It didn't send, so we'll exit and wait for peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers to call sendData again
        return;
    }

    // We're not sending an EOM, so we're sending data

    // Is there any left to send?

    if (self.sendDataIndex >= imageData.length) {

        // No data left.  Do nothing
        return;
    }

    // There's data left, so send until the callback fails, or we're done.

    BOOL didSend = YES;

    while (didSend) {

        // Make the next chunk

        // Work out how big it should be
        NSInteger amountToSend = imageData.length - self.sendDataIndex;

        // Can't be longer than 20 bytes
        if (amountToSend > NOTIFY_MTU) amountToSend = NOTIFY_MTU;

        // Copy out the data we want
        NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithBytes:imageData.bytes+self.sendDataIndex length:amountToSend];

        // Send it
        didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:chunk forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

        // If it didn't work, drop out and wait for the callback
        if (!didSend) {
            return;
        }

        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Sent: %@", stringFromData);

        // It did send, so update our index
        self.sendDataIndex += amountToSend;

        // Was it the last one?
        if (self.sendDataIndex >= imageData.length) {

            // It was - send an EOM

            // Set this so if the send fails, we'll send it next time
            sendingEOM = YES;

            // Send it
            BOOL eomSent = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:[@"EOM" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

            if (eomSent) {
                // It sent, we're all done
                sendingEOM = NO;

                NSLog(@"Sent: EOM");
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't maintain order?  You can set your attribute to `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` and wait until you get the callback to `didWriteValueForCharacteristic:` before sending the next chunk, but this will be slower.

Comment: BLE is the wrong tool for this job.  Why are you trying to use BLE when you can use regular Bluetooth?

Comment: @Paulw11 - Yes Paul it would be slow, thats why I do not want to use it. I need to use notify and still maintain packet drops and the order.

Comment: @TimTisdall - I need to use BLE as it consumes low energy. Since I am making an application which sends data over BLE for a long time. Hence using regular Bluetooth is not a good approach I guess.

Comment: BLE is low energy because it sends much less data at slower speeds.  If you just quickly send your image file over regular Bluetooth and then disconnect you're probably better off.  If you have to maintain a connection, I'm not really sure how the two compare, though.

Comment: @TimTisdall apps don't have access to BT2.1 for file transfer on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 - I'm just replying based on my knowledge of BLE...  :)  I don't know anything about how iOS messes about with this stuff.  It's pretty silly to force apps to transfer large binary across BLE.

Comment: @TimTisdall - I were thinking of creating a packet structure like sending total number of packets, current packet index and length of the packet and then append the image data to it. So that at the receiving end after receiving it may tell me what data is lost and i may be able to send it again. Whereas I wanted to avoid doing all this. I thought may be iOS provides something like this by default so that I do not need to handle it explicitly.What do you say?

Comment: It's all "putting a screw in with a hammer" to me.  I have no knowledge of iOS.

Comment: @TimTisdall I agree that BLE isn't good for large transfers but on iOS  apps only have access to the BLE GATT profile, so you have to work with wha you have.

Comment: i have the similar problem :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433122/ble-image-transfer-between-2-ios-devices-using-corebluetooth
@Paulw11