# BLE: image transfer between 2 ios devices using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have 2 iOS devices: one is Peripheral and the other Central.
I want that the data would be image.

I have tried with a string value and it is working fine but with image I get this error:

> read_user_chunkIDOT:1221: invalid PNG file: no valid iEnd chunk

Also I can see that the bytes are different (`<CBCharacteristic: 0x1c40bde20, UUID = 2A38, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO> Optional(526 bytes)`), they are larger when I get them.

This is the peripheral:

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "maiden") {
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
        let base64 = data?.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        let char = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: CHAR_UUID, properties: [.read], value: base64!, permissions: [.readable])
        let myRoei = CBMutableService(type: RX_UUID, primary: true)
        
        myRoei.characteristics = [char]
        cameraPeripheralManager.add(myRoei)
        cameraPeripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[RX_UUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: advertisementData])
    }
```

This is the Central inside didUpdateValueFor characteristic:

```
print(characteristic.value as Any)
    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case CHAR_UUID:
        let image = UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: characteristic.value!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!)

        self.imageView.image = image
        _ = bodyLocation(from: characteristic)
    case RX_UUID: break
       // onHeartRateReceived(bpm)
    default:
        print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
    }
```

I would like to know where I am wrong.

Comment: First, if you specify the value when you create the characteristic, then it will have a fixed value that cannot change. You need to not specify the value when you create the characteristic so that you can update the value later. Second, BLE has a small MTU; typically 20 bytes or so.  You need to break your data up into multiple chunks and send those. You can send binary data; there is no need to base64 encode your data for ble.

Comment: @Paulw11Thanks!
So if i wanna break my data to chunks i need to change the char to .notify.
Do you have an example how can i break it and then advertise it?

Comment: Use a `Data` temp object that will get all the chunk values, then append them and recreate your image. In other words the `didUpdateValueFor()` should be called multiple times, receiving piece by piece the whole large data.

Comment: Just did it!
thanks mate

Comment: do you have source code please share it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed doing so with this code:

```
func sendData() {
    if sendingEOM {
        // send it
        let didSend = cameraPeripheralManager?.updateValue(
            "EOM".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
            for: char!,
            onSubscribedCentrals: nil
        )
        // Did it send?
        if (didSend == true) {
            // It did, so mark it as sent
            sendingEOM = false
            print("Sent: EOM")
        }
        return
    }
    
    // We're not sending an EOM, so we're sending data
    
    // Is there any left to send?
    guard sendDataIndex! < (dataToSend?.count)! else {
        // No data left.  Do nothing
        return
    }
    
    // There's data left, so send until the callback fails, or we're done.
    var didSend = true
    
    while didSend {
        // Make the next chunk
        
        // Work out how big it should be
        var amountToSend = dataToSend!.count - sendDataIndex!;
        
        // Can't be longer than 20 bytes
        if (amountToSend > NOTIFY_MTU) {
            amountToSend = NOTIFY_MTU;
        }
        
        // Copy out the data we want
        let chunk = dataToSend!.withUnsafeBytes{(body: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            return Data(
                bytes: body + sendDataIndex!,
                count: amountToSend
            )
        }
        
        // Send it
        didSend = cameraPeripheralManager!.updateValue(
            chunk as Data,
            for: char!,
            onSubscribedCentrals: nil
        )
        
        // If it didn't work, drop out and wait for the callback
        if (!didSend) {
            return
        }
        
        let stringFromData = NSString(
            data: chunk as Data,
            encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        )
        
        print("Sent: \(String(describing: stringFromData))")
        
        // It did send, so update our index
        sendDataIndex! += amountToSend;
        
        // Was it the last one?
        if (sendDataIndex! >= dataToSend!.count) {
            
            // It was - send an EOM
            
            // Set this so if the send fails, we'll send it next time
            sendingEOM = true
            
            // Send it
            let eomSent = cameraPeripheralManager!.updateValue(
                "EOM".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
                for: char!,
                onSubscribedCentrals: nil
            )
            
            if (eomSent) {
                // It sent, we're all done
                sendingEOM = false
                print("Sent: EOM")
            }
            
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is the client side:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print(characteristic.value as Any)
    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case Constants.CHAR_UUID:
        imageView.image = nil
        print("Char value: \(String(describing: characteristic.value))")
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        if  let stringFromData = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
            
            if  (stringFromData.isEqual(to:"EOM")){
                countNumberOfImages += 1
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
               // peripheral.setNotifyValue(false, for: characteristic)
                print("Image number: \(countNumberOfImages)")

                let end = NSDate()   // <<<<<<<<<<   end time
                print("Total data: \(data.length)")
                
                let start = NSDate() // <<<<<<<<<< Start time
                
                data.setData(NSData() as Data)
                //totalData.setData(NSData() as Data)
               // centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
                
            } else {
                // Otherwise, just add the data on to what we already have
                data.append(characteristic.value!)
                totalData.append(characteristic.value!)
                count += 1
               // print("Times: +\(count)")
                // Log it
                print("Received: \(data.length)")
            }
        } else {
            data.append(characteristic.value!)
            totalData.append(characteristic.value!)
            count += 1
          //  print("Times: +\(count)")
            // Log it
            print("Received: \(data.length)")
        }
    default:
        print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
    }
}
```

Very useful code that helps you break the data into chunks and deliver the last chunk with a string to notify the central device that the transfer finished.

Comment: Could you please add your code for image. I think this code is for text sending by chunk.For long text, it works fine. I actually need the image data conversion and after sending the data and how do your receive it and convert it to image ? i was struggling with this.

Comment: @JamshedAlam hi,
This is the actual way to send the image in data chunks.
I will add the client size to show how i am getting the chunks and build from them uiimage

Comment: Could you please have a look on this code ? I am sending image from peripheral screen and converted image in captureCurrentText() method. How to receive this data ? Or from where ? Any error with my conversion after receiving data ? link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yy2VnvMqqTjIcfyANWxb-2zD_AHxyG-4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? with the "didUpdateValueFor"?
There you can see the receiving side?
Take a look and tell me if you don't understand

Comment: I set this inside the  didUpdateValueFor method , and nothing changed.   if (nextChunk == Device.EOM) {   self.imageView1.image = UIImage.init(data: dataBuffer! as Data) } I converted the image like this :      let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)! ;
            let str =  imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters) ; 
            let data: NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: str , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)! ; 
             dataToSend = data as Data // i sent this data.

Comment: @JamshedAlam please open a chat and we will check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190627/discussion-between-ironroei-and-jamshed-alam).

Comment: Please can you share demo source code? i am facing multiple errors while adding above code